# Can't set a fixed position for Swing elements

Tags: java, swing, position, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm having some problems while trying to create a simple UI using Swing. This is the window that i want to achive:[image: Desired result]

I want to have two scrollable JTextAreas on the sides, and also to have two buttons in the middle of the window.

Here is the code i have:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextArea inputArea;

    private JTextArea outputArea;

    private JButton encriptButton, decriptButton;

    public MainWindow() {
        super();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        this.setSize(900, 600);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        inputArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(inputArea);
        js.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,400));

        outputArea = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane js2 = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
        js2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 400));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        encriptButton = new JButton("Encript");
        decriptButton = new JButton("Decript");

        panel.add(encriptButton);
        panel.add(decriptButton);

        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(js, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.getContentPane().add(js2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

Now if i do something like this:

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
window.initUI();
window.setVisible(true);
```

I get the following result:
[image: Result]

I don't know how to position the two buttons in the center of the window. And i also don't know how to set a fixed size for JTextArea. That's it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider:

- Using a BoxLayout for the overall GUI
- Creating a middle JPanel that uses GridBagLayout to hold the two buttons.
- Then adding to the outer BoxLayout-using JPanel one JScrollPane, the middle JPanel, and the other JScrollPane.

The key to all this is to try to visualize what the layout managers should be doing, and then nesting your JPanels, each with their own layout manager to get your goal to work.

For example, this GUI

[image]

can be produced by this code:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutEg extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final int ROWS = 30;
   private static final int COLS = 30;
   private static final int GBC_GAP = 10;
   private JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);
   private JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea(ROWS, COLS);
   private JButton encryptButton = new JButton("Encrypt");
   private JButton decryptButton = new JButton("Decrypt");

   public LayoutEg() {
      JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
      gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
      gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
      gbc.gridheight = 1;
      gbc.gridwidth = 1;
      gbc.insets = new Insets(GBC_GAP, GBC_GAP, GBC_GAP, GBC_GAP);

      // setting the weightx and weighty of 0 is what forces the buttons 
      // in the center to bunch together
      gbc.weightx = 0;  
      gbc.weighty = 0;  
      gbc.gridx = 0;
      gbc.gridy = 0;
      centerPanel.add(encryptButton, gbc);

      gbc.gridy = 1;
      centerPanel.add(decryptButton, gbc);

      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GBC_GAP, GBC_GAP, GBC_GAP, GBC_GAP));
      setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea1));
      add(centerPanel);
      add(new JScrollPane(textArea2));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Layout Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new LayoutEg());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to think about using the [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) to achieve this design, as it has better controls for anchoring where you want your buttons to show up. You can actually do your cell padding in the GridBagConstraints, or you can think about using [Border(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/border/Border.html).

Comment: Thx. I'll have to inform myself on those topics. I'm used to lay out the UI using user-friendly tools. Don't have much experience on coding them myself.